# Find a substring in a string with PowerShell and trim

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to trim a string with PowerShell.

Let's say you have the following string:

> Test test test test test test /abc test test test

I want to 'find' the '/a' in the string and ultimately get the "abc" by finding the next space.

Is that doable with PowerShell?

Answer (score 6):

```
 $positionSlashA = "Test test test test test test /abc test test test".IndexOf("/a")
 $result1 = "Test test test test test test /abc test test test".Substring($positionSlashA)
 $positionfirstspace = $result1.IndexOf(" ")
 $result1.Substring(0, $positionfirstspace)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that your string is $testString. This code snipped will work. It will grab the characters that begin with /a until the next white space.

```
$testString = "Test test test test test test /abc test test test"
$matchString = $testString -match '/a\w*\s' | % {$Matches.Values -replace '/','' -replace'\s',''}
Write-Host $matchString
```

Or with one line and not writing output. I only wrote output in the previous example to show you the result.

```
$testString = "Test test test test test test /abc test test test" -match '/a\w*\s' | % {$Matches.Values -replace '/','' -replace'\s',''}
```

Comment: Does it change anything that what I'm actually looking for is \a (backslash a)?   Because I tried your code and it isn't working.   Can you tell me what the \/ mean as well as the \s?   Where is the space in all of that?

Comment: I am sorry, I just fixed the code snippet and it should work now.  And the \ leading the regular expression in the match is to escape a special character.  In this case, it is completely unnecessary.  The \s is the white space character, so technically if you want abc with no white space proceeding it, you have to remove that.

Comment: I have been running the code on my machine and it works.  I have even made it more efficient with this method.

Comment: $testString = "Test test test test test test /abc test test test" -match '/a\S*' | % {$Matches.Values -replace '/',''}

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [named capture group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#named-captures)

```
> if ('Test test test test test test /abc test test test' -match '/(?<Token>[a-z]+)') { $Matches.Token }
```

```
abc
```

This approach allows you to extract exactly the token that follows the '/'.  No need to trim '/', or trailing spaces.